# Access Type of Tuple3

Tags: scala

I try to compile [this scala class](https://github.com/harrah/up/blob/master/Dense.scala) but the following function is not accepted by scalac:

```
def toTuple3[T <: Triple[Dense,Dense,Dense]](implicit dra: DRep[T#_1], drb: DRep[T#_2], drc: DRep[T#_3]) : (Int, Int, Int) =
    (toInt[T#_1], toInt[T#_2], toInt[T#_3])
```

It says:

> Dense.scala:130: error: type T_1 is not a member of type parameter T

Same for T_2 and T_3.

How can I access the types of the `Triple`or `Tuple3`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the question, but `val x: Tuple3[Int, Int, Int] = (1, 2, 3)` and `x._1`, `x._2`, and `x._3` do not answer your question?

Comment: With that I would get the values of the parameters, not their types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to take the types of the tuple type arguments as your own type arguments

```
def toTuple3[A <: Dense, B <: Dense, C <: Dense, T <: Tuple3[A,B,C]](implicit dra: DRep[A], drb: DRep[B], drc: DRep[C]) : (Int, Int, Int) =
(toInt[A], toInt[B], toInt[C])
```

Comment: Well, that actually works! However I wonder why the original code compiled under Scala 2.8. The #-operator seemed like a convenient way to achieve what is needed in this example - why it is impossible to use in current Scala versions?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure, I didn't start using Scala seriously until late in 2.9.